# How can I use NTLM authentication with node using domain, user, and password?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, python-requests, ntlm, ntlm-authentication

I want to authenticate against a board game website called yucata.de using nodejs.

### Via Python

Looking at the headers with Chrome devtools, it looks like it uses a `ASP.NET_SessionId`, a `.Stackify.Run`, and a 168 hex value for `Yucata` inside of its cookie, with content type `multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary`. Given the ASP.NET component, I tried using python's NTLM library, and it works with the example code given on the main page of [requests_ntlm](https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm):

```py
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

requests.get("http://www.yucata.de/en/Overview",
              auth=HttpNtlmAuth(f'domain\\{user}',
              password
))
```

Overview here is a route that requires authentication.

### Attempts with node and httpntlm

Using the example code for [httpntlm](https://github.com/SamDecrock/node-http-ntlm), I get a 401:

```js
var httpntlm = require('httpntlm');

httpntlm.get({
    url: "https://www.yucata.de",
    username: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    workstation: 'yucata',
    domain: 'www.yucata.de'
}, function (err, res){
    if(err) return err;

    console.log(res.headers);
    console.log(res.body);
});
```

The title (combined with an h3) of the response is

> 401 - Nicht autorisiert: Zugriff aufgrund ung�ltiger Anmeldeinformationen verweigert. Die angegebenen Anmeldeinformationen berechtigen Sie nicht, dieses Verzeichnis oder diese Seite anzuzeigen.

Which, translated to English via google translate, is

> 401 - Unauthorized: Access denied due to invalid credentials. The credentials provided do not authorize you to view this directory or this page.

I would think that the code above would work as httpntlm is a port of the python library.
I have double checked that the username and password are the same in both code snippets.

### Question

Why do I get a 401 with httpntlm using domain, user, pass when it's possible to use the library it's ported from, requests_ntlm, with the same values?

Comment: maybe you're using ntlmv2, it doesn't seem supported by this lib: https://github.com/SamDecrock/node-http-ntlm/issues/59